# blank table returns mysql_num_rows($result) =1

Tags: php, mysql

my query is

```
 $result=SELECT MAX(surveyID) as surveyID  FROM `sg_count`WHERE userID=$user
```

where `sg_count` table has no records

but `mysql_num_rows($result)` returns 1.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.  Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. You are querying, right? All I see is one line of code.

Comment: You're welcome. Did you find the problem?

Comment: Post syntactically-valid code that results in the reported problem. That is *not* what is being tried.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Hard to say what the OP wants to do. Given the single line of code and no explanation, it's anybody's guess.

Comment: You need to show us more code and to let us know what results you want to get. Your question is unclear. Update your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregating functions like `max` and `count` *will* return one row (without a grouping clause), that's their nature.

By way of example, `count(*)` on an empty table will give you *one* row with the value `0`.

I suspect, although I haven't tried, that you'll be getting a single row in your query with a `NULL` value. That's how all the other DBs I've used handle it. Assuming the column is non-NULL specified, you can use that return value to detect the "no row" case. Even if it allows NULLs, that may still be workable, it depends on what you want to do in that case.

Otherwise, you're probably better off checking the count as well with something like:

```
select   count(*) as quant,
         max(surveyID) as surveyID
from     sg_count
where    userID = 'somebody'
```

Then, if `quant` is zero, you know there were no rows. If it's non-zero, there *were* rows and the maximum value of `surveyID` is in the other column.

Comment: Query's not failing, so as to what OP wants to do with it, is anyone's guess. But this is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes thats quite true. When you select that record it will yield one row:

```
+----------+
| surveyID |
+----------+
| NULL     |
+----------+

$count = $query->num_rows; // 1
$results = $query->fetch_assoc();
echo $results['surveyID']; // NULL
```